# Sorting ListBox Items

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, listbox

So I have two ListBoxes. Listbox1 gathers files from a directory and I have an add button to add selected files from Listbox1 over to Listbox2.

Is there a way to manually sort these items? Maybe with an up down buttons?

The reason I'd like to sort/reorder is I'll have a process that will run those selected files and each file will have to produce another file unique to the filename.

A quick example would be process FILE1.txt and produce FILE1.pdf, etc.

Is there an easier way to accomplish the sort/reorder?

**UPDATE**

Here is currently how I'm populating my `listbox1`, before adding anything to `listbox2`, which is the ListBox I'd like to have sorted so way or another.

```
Dim directoryInfo As _
    New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
Dim fileInfos() As System.IO.FileInfo

fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
For Each fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo In fileInfos
    ListBox1.DataSource = _list
    _list.Add(fileInfo.Name)
    _list.Sort()
Next

'Refresh Listbox1
ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
ListBox1.DataSource = _list
```

Comment: You should remove `ListBox1.DataSource = _list` from the For-Each-loop. It is enough to refresh the ListBox after the loop has terminated and `ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing` is not necessary the first time. It's only necessary later, in order to force the `DataSource` to refresh; otherwise, when you assign the same list again it will not do anything, even if you have added items to the list meanwhile.

Comment: Call `_list.Sort()` after `Next`. There is no point in sorting the list after each single item addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-binding instead of adding the items one by one to the `ListBox`. I suggest you to add the files to a list first then sort the list and assign it to the `ListBox`'s `DataSource`.

Define the list a class member

```
Private _list As New List(Of String)()
```

Assign it to the `ListBox`

```
 listBox1.DataSource = _list
```

Then add new list entry with

```
_list.Add("new file")
_list.Sort()

' Refresh the ListBox
listBox1.DataSource = Nothing
listBox1.DataSource = _list
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to implement your own sorting order then implement a `IComparer(Of String)`

```
Class MyFileComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer _
        Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare 

        Const  AlwaysFirst As String = "FILE1"

        Dim x = If(x.Contains(AlwaysFirst), "1_", "2_") & x
        Dim y = If(y.Contains(AlwaysFirst), "1_", "2_") & y

        ' Note: If "FILE1" appears always at the end then this would be better
        'Dim x = If(x.EndsWith(AlwaysFirst & ".txt"), "1_", "2_") & x
        'Dim y = If(y.EndsWith(AlwaysFirst & ".txt"), "1_", "2_") & y

        ' Normalize strings (e.g. if "File_123.txt" = ""File 123.txt")
        x = x.Replace("_"C, " "C)
        y = y.Replace("_"C, " "C)

        Return x.CompareTo(y)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you can sort like this

```
Static comparer =  New MyFileComparer()

_list.Sort(comparer)
```

---

**UPDATE** #2

I do not know how your files are named exactly, however if they always end with `"FILE<number>.<ext>"` you could also change the file name for the string comparison like this:

Original file names

```
abc_FILE1.txt
abc_123_FILE2.txt
sssd_FILE23.txt
xxx_24_FILE073.txt
```

Prepared file names

```
FILE001_abc.txt
FILE002_abc_123.txt
FILE023_sssd.txt
FILE073_xxx_24.txt
```

Now the `Compare` method can determine the result simply with

```
Return x_prepared.CompareTo(y_prepared)
```

Comment: What if the filesnames were not the same each time? Meaning, today a file might be named as xyz_FILE1.txt or xyx_123_FILE1.txt. I'm looking for some way to always get a certain file as the first item in the listbox and so on.

Comment: The `Sort` routine has an overload that accepts a `IComparaer<T>`. This allows you to implement your own sorting order.

Comment: I'll sure look into your suggestion. I'm still pretty new when it comes to VB (teaching myself), so I may have other questions.

Comment: You reminded me that you are programming in VB. I changed my code from C# to VB.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to show you my updated code I currently have? I've seen an example of the comparer being used, not 100% sure how to use it based on how I'm populating my listbox.

Comment: The `Compare` method has to return `-1` if `x` goes before `y`, `0` if both are equal and `+1` if `x` goes after `y`. You can add the code to your question. But please, only the relevant parts; not long listings. If you indent the code by four spaces and put an empty line before and after it, it will be formatted as code automatically.

Comment: I'll take a look at this tonight and try some things out tomorrow. I updated my question to include the current way I'm populating my listbox, with the addition of your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on Olivier's answer, perhaps a [Sorted List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) may work for you?

You also could use OrderBy to sort the items if you need more than an alpha-name sort.

```
 var sorted = from m in myCollection select m orderBy m.FileName;
```

(syntax may be off)